# JAVA: Install and use my postgresql database without installing pgadmin

Tags: java, postgresql

I have created a java application that uses postgresql database and now after exporting the executable jar file I want that the application connect to the database without installing pgadmin.
Of course I'm using "JDBC" but (when I give the application to someone to use it) I don't want to install pgadmin I just want to install only the application and database's files.
is it possible ?

Comment: The user needs to have Postgres installed anyways. The datafiles by themselves won't do any good.

Comment: But you never have to install pgadmin when installing Postgres anyway.

Comment: @X.L.Ant can you explain more pls.

Comment: PostGres and pgadmin are two different products, pgadmin relying on postgres to work (it has no point on its own). But you can download and install postgres on a machine without installing pgadmin, both are totally independant products. But as Kayaman said, you have to install postgres on every machine you want to run your database on.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I'm sry but I can't find the installation of postgresql without pgAdmin.

Comment: I don't know if they provide installers without pgadmin, but you can download the binaries [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and choose what you want to redistribute with your application (some info [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html)).